# How many ways can I split up a string of length $n$ so that the length of the split strings add up to $n$?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, if the string is abc, $n=3$,
then the different ways it can be split is

a/b/c($1+1+1$), a/bc($1+2$), ab/c($2+1$), abc($3$)

which is $4$ ways.

Similarly, if I have the string abcd, $n=4$, then it can be split into the following lengths:

$4,1+3,3+1,2+2,1+1+2,1+2+1,2+1+1,1+1+1+1$

which is $8$ different ways.

I can see the total number of ways is equal to $2^{n-1}$. I would like someone to explain/prove theoretically why it is so.

Comment: Isn't this just a convoluted way of asking: Given a positive integer $n$, how many possible [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) are there for $n$?

Comment: There is a proof in the Wikipedia article to which Aiden Chow linked.

Comment: The [direct link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)#Number_of_compositions) to the proof if you don't want to look through the whole Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see why it is $2^{n-1}$, represent all *binary* numbers from $0$ to $2^{n-1}$ (not included), say $n=3$ for "abc" we have $4$ values

```
00  => 0
01  => 1
10  => 2
11  => 3
```

with $0$ meaning "no separation", $1$ means "separation" between characters, $aS_1bS_0c$ that gives you

```
00  => abc
01  => ab|c
10  => a|bc
11  => a|b|c
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Thanks!